# Which conditions must a query meet so that it can be translated to the SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

After migrating my ASP.NET Core 2.2 app to ASP.NET Core 3.0 I continue to get problems...

This time Linq-to-SQL queries that used to be working are now failing with an exception of the form:

```
The LINQ expression 'blahblah' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Great, so I go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 .

What am I reading there? That pre-3.0 versions used to accept queries that couldn't be evaluated on server, but this is mostly no longer the case now, and also:

> If EF Core detects an expression, in any place other than the top-level projection, which can't be translated to the server, then it throws a runtime exception. See [how query works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works) to understand how EF Core determines what can't be translated to server.

Oh, one more link. OK, let's follow it:

> The database provider identifies which parts of the query can be evaluated in the database

!!! I was supposed to be able to read under this link how is it determined what can't be translated to the server so I can amend my query properly !!!

Well, all I know is that *the database provider determines this*. This is still not helpful for me.

I honestly thought that this particular query would be well-translatable to the SQL because it boils down to (somewhat complex) comparison of a few numbers (with a lot of parenthesis and `||`s and `&&`s between these parenthesis).

So for the sake of readability and code reuse the query uses three helper methods, two of which are properties defined in the model class, groups these numbers into two tuples and one enum... But come on, enums convert to integers, a tuple knows it's length so comparing them easily reduces to comparing their elements, etc...

Well it would seem things are not that nice, instead I have to do some/all of:

- Removing helper methods, copy-paste their code into the query.
- Manually unpack tuples.
- Manually convert enums to integers (ugh the model instance defines an enum!)

How can I know which of the above is necessary?

How can I know how do I have to construct my queries so that I don't run into such problems?

Which conditions do queries have to meet to be translatable to the db language?

Comment: One thing is for sure true for ALL query providers - custom (helper) methods cannot be translated. Remember that the query translators have no access to the source code, hence have no idea what custom method is doing inside. Same for unmapped (helper) properties.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oops, that's tough. Is copy-pasting sometimes complex conditions the only alternative? Seems like readability and maintainability nightmare!

Comment: That's true. But it is what it is. The solution requires expression composition, but C# compiler does not help with that either. Some 3rd party libraries are trying to address it - like [LinqKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/), NeinLinq [Lambda injection](https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq/#lambda-injection) and similar.

Comment: @IvanStoev Maybe something like `private IQueryable<SomeType> AddCondition(IQueryable<SomeType> query) => query.Where(st => st.SomeMappedProp <= st.OtherMappedProp);`??

Answer (score 0):

[Compare EF Core & EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/) has a *Feature comparison* table.

[Breaking changes included in EF Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) and [What's new in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/index) may also be relevant.

---

One option may be to use EF with ASP .NET Core targeting .NET Framework.

The tutorial is [Get Started with ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-3.0#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-aspnet-core-project).

Please note that while this would be ASP.NET Core, it will not be .NET Core any more.

> To use Entity Framework 6, your project has to compile against .NET Framework, as Entity Framework 6 doesn't support .NET Core.

Comment: To my understanding: The problem is not that my project depends on some feature that was removed in 3.0. Rather, the problem is that I *thought* that some part of my project was working while it was not, only that 2.2 was (somewhat) silently ignoring that while 3.0 throws.

Comment: Would you be able to share the expression?